# Does Ignite support GPB serialized data

Tags: ignite

New user to Ignite here.

We have protocol buffer serialized binary data that would like to stored into ignite via memcached binary protocol, and wonder if Ignite supports gpb serialization out of the box?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cross-posting from [userlist](http://apache-ignite-users.70518.x6.nabble.com/Does-Ignite-support-GPB-serialized-data-td24515.html):

Ignite does not have special support for protocol buffers.

You are welcome to implement [Binarylizable](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/binary/Binarylizable.html) or [Externalizable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Externalizable.html) interfaces on your objects to specify serialization for them.

You can also specify BinarySerializer for types that you do not control by [putting them into BinaryConfiguration](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/binary-marshaller#section-configuring-binary-objects).setTypeConfigurations() and using that one with [IgniteConfiguration](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/configuration/IgniteConfiguration.html#setBinaryConfiguration-org.apache.ignite.configuration.BinaryConfiguration-).